# How does EncFS extpass work

Tags: encryption, passwords, passwd

Programs like encfs or git have an option where in we can set an external application to get the password for them.

My question is twofold:

1. What are the necessary characteristics for these external programs?  That is to say, once they read the password from the user using what ever means, how should they return it to the calling programs?
2. How do these programs read the password from the external agent?